# Как сделать так чтобы при скролинге исчезал элемент из страницы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так чтобы при прокрутке страницы вниз заданный элемент или блок исчезал а когда прокручивается страница вверх появлялся.

Comment: myvzar DreamChild спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var tempScrollTop = 0, 
currentScrollTop = 0;

$(window).on('scroll', 
    function() {        
        currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();        
        if (tempScrollTop < currentScrollTop )        
            $('#md2').fadeOut();

        else 
            if (tempScrollTop > currentScrollTop )            
                $('#md2').fadeIn();                                   
            tempScrollTop = currentScrollTop;  
    })
```

Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/29EKm/) на jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()>70) {
            LogoTop.fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

После 70 px - убирается лого