# Как удалить div при скролле страницы?

Tags: javascript

Как удалить блок, например, с классом `.class1`? При скролле страницы вниз или вверх.

Comment: А что значит "при скролле"? Вот загрузилась страница, и как только скролл задергался хотя бы на 1 пиксель - сразу удалить?)

Comment: вот вариант по лучше https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/307799/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b?rq=1, это я для быстрого поиска.

Comment: @zis ну у вас написано при прокрутке "удалялся" элемент а по ссылке "исчезал" это совсем разные вещи. Ответы соответственно то же разные будут)

Answer (score 0):

Ну допустим так.

```js
var cont = document.querySelector('.class1');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (cont === null) return;
  cont.remove();
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
  
}

.title {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div class="title">Не скроль по братски!!!</div>
</div>
```